# Avoid multiple delete statements with Spring Data JPA on ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have some entities that are related with a `@ManyToMany` like this (irrelevant fields, constructors and methods removed for brevity):

```
@Entity
public class Profile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "profile_skills",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Skill> skills;

    public void addSkill(Skill skill) {
        this.skills.add(requireNonNull(skill));
    }

    public Set<Skill> getSkills() {
        return unmodifiableSet(skills);
    }

    public void removeSkill(Skill skill) {
        this.skills.remove(skill);
    }
}

@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Skill {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And in a service class I'm updating Profile with new Skills like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProfileUpdaterService implements ProfileUpdater {
    private final ProfileRepository profileRepository;
    private final SkillRepository skillRepository;

    ProfileUpdaterService(ProfileRepository profileRepository, SkillRepository skillRepository) {
        this.profileRepository = profileRepository;
        this.skillRepository = skillRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public WebResponse updateData(Supplier<User> userSupplier, ProfileRequest request) {
        Profile profile = profileRepository.findByOwner(userSupplier.get())
            .map(updateProfileValues(request))
            .orElseGet(() -> makeProfile(userSupplier, request));
        Profile save = profileRepository.save(profile);
        return save != null ? () -> OperationResult.PROFILE_UPDATED : () -> OperationResult.OPERATION_FAILED;
    }

    private Function<Profile, Profile> updateProfileValues(ProfileRequest request) {
        return profile -> {
            updateSkills(request, profile);
            return profile;
        };
    }

    private void updateSkills(ProfileRequest request, Profile profile) {
        Set<Skill> requestSkills = extractSkillsFromRequest(request).collect(toSet());
        requestSkills.forEach(profile::addSkill);
        Set<Skill> removedSkills = profile.getSkills().stream()
            .filter(skill -> !requestSkills.contains(skill))
            .collect(toSet());
        removedSkills.forEach(profile::removeSkill);
    }

    private Stream<Skill> extractSkillsFromRequest(ProfileRequest request) {
        if (request.getSkills().isEmpty()) {
            return Stream.empty();
        }
        return request.getSkills().stream()
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .map(this::findOrSaveSkill)
            .distinct();
    }

    private Skill findOrSaveSkill(String s) {
        return skillRepository.findById(s)
            .orElseGet(() -> skillRepository.save(Skill.of(s)));
    }
}
```

TL;DR: I get a new set of Skills from a request and I have to add the ones that are not present in the Profile and delete the ones not present in the request.

This way of doing it performs one delete statement on the join table for each skill that is removed from the Profile. What would be a (clean) way to combine this into a single delete statement?

NOTE: This is a Spring Boot 1.5.12 app with Spring Data JPA 1.11.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, of course, my insufficient knowledge of Hibernate. This problem can be fixed easily setting Hibernate's `jdbc.batch_size` property. In Spring Boot, on `application.properties` add this line:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
```

And done, now Hibernate batches up to 20 statements.